# Unwanted Perlin Noise result

Tags: random, perlin-noise, noise

I've finally managed to write a working Lua version of Perlin's improved noise for Love 2D. However, when I run it, i get this:

[image]

Which is just fine, I guess. But I would like something that looks more like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The latter image looks more like diamond-squares algorithm..

Comment: No, it's Perlin Noise, only with multiple octaves

Comment: Ok, but to phrase it differently - maybe you might want to look into DS-algorithm and compare?

Comment: Oh, don't worry, I solved my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to learn how the terms Octave, Persistence, Frequency, and Lacunarity are used.  What you have is a good first step, it looks just like noise should.

The basic idea is that you need to combine multiple noise sources into one result to achieve the final look.  This combination can be something simple like addition, but you can take many mathematical operations.

In the end a typical example for your grainy clouds looks like this: Map = Map1 + (Map2 / 2) + (Map3 / 4) + (Map4 / 8)

For reference and examples: [Start here](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/docs/classnoise_1_1module_1_1Perlin.html)

Comment: Thanks man. I tought octaves, frequency and amplitude were a unique feature of "False" Perlin noise (value noise) just like gradients only are in "True" Perlin noise.

Comment: Definitely going to read that article.